# vertical-align: middle without using table

Tags: html, css

am trying to make the text appear as shown in the attached image:

Comment: What have you tried? Try to use Google more: https://www.google.cz/search?q=vertical+align+text

Comment: do you have a sample code for this?

Comment: not even an ATTEMPT at showing us your current code. It's ok in asking, but at least try putting some effort into your question!

Comment: I try this: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> lab3-CSS </title>

<style type="text/css">
.Div1{
float:left;
width:100%;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3px;
}

.Div2{
background-color:#999999;
float:left;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;

}

.Div2left{
width:200px;
float:left;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}

.Div2right{
width:200px;
float:right;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}

Comment: .Div3{
background-color:#666666;
float:right;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}

.Div3left{
background-color:#666666;
width:200px;
float:left;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}

.Div3right{
background-color:#666666;
width:200px;
float:right;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}


</style>

</head>

Comment: <body>
<div id="D1" class="Div1"> 
    <div id="D2" class="Div2"> 
      <div id="D2left" class="Div2left"> <p> is an oven-baked flat bread typically topped with tomato sauce and cheese. </p> </div>
      <div id="D2right" class="Div2right"> <img src="http://papajohns.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/pizza.png" width="200" alt="pizza"> </div>
    </div>

Comment: <div id="D3" class="Div3"> 
      <div id="D3left" class="Div3left"> <p>Pizza is an oven-baked flat bread typically topped with tomato sauce and cheese. Baked variously in coal, wood, gas, and electric ovens, it is generally supplemented with a selection of meats, vegetables, and condiments.</p> </div>
      <div id="D3right" class="Div3right"> <img src="http://papajohns.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/pizza.png" width="100" alt="pizza">  </div>
    </div> 

</div>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use tables, just `display:table` and `display:table-cell`: fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nwder8qy/

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to support [**'modern' browsers**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), then flex boxes are the way to go.

Basically you will need a parent container like this:

```
<div id="parent">

    <!-- child elements here -->

</div
```

with css styling similar to this:

```
#parent {display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-around; height: 400px;}
```

Be sure to set a height for this parent container (and a lesser height and width for the child elements).

Then child elements within that container will be horizontally and vertically centered.

(You can see a good summary of flexbox css here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ )

Comment: Leave a fiddle to so that everyone can check your answer

Comment: @Akshay, there's no point really adding a ['fiddle'](http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/qIAwr) - although I don't think it's the best option here since OP just wants text vertically aligned, so Lucian's answer is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Made one just like in the image see if this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/azounfvd/1/

HTML

```
<div id="a">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301"/>
<p>"
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
 labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco   laboris
 nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
 esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 
 in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#a{
width:700px;
height:350px;
border:1px solid;
}

img{
float:right;
}

p{
margin: 50px auto;
}
```